# how to Get Value from IKeyValuePair<Platform::Guid,Platform:: Object>

Tags: windows-runtime, c++-cx

I am trying to get the value from

```cpp
IKeyValuePair<Platform::Guid,Platform:: Object>
```

Say for example I have Api Called SomeApi() which returns `IKeyValuePair<Platform::Guid,Platform:: Object>`

C++ Code:

```cpp
auto res =  SomeApi();    
String ^str = res->key; // I am able to get Guid Here
```

Now How to get Value from it

`res->value` returns object but how to know type of object and get the value from it.

if I do

```cpp
String^ value =  res->value.ToString(); // this returns something else not value
```

Please explain me through code how can i get value from `IKeyValuePair`.

Comment: Next time don't use auto and you will find out why.

Answer (score 1):

You should cast from Platform::Object^ to the underlying type, eg:

```
String^ value = safe_cast<String^>(res->value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String^ value =  res->value->ToString();
```